Sum of previous numbers in Java using recursion
I'm trying to solve this homework problem:

Write a method called sumOfPreviousN that takes two integers and returns the sum of the first number minus multiples of the second number. For example:
Write a method called sumOfPreviousN that takes two integers and returns the sum of the first number minus multiples of the second number. For example, sumOfPreviousN(9, 4) would return 6 because it would add 5 + 1. sumOfPreviousN(20, 6) would return 24 because it would add 14 + 8 + 2.

We haven't learned loops yet, so we're only allowed to use recursion.
Here's what I have so far:
public class help {
    public static int sumOfPreviousN(int num1, int num2) {
        if (num1 <= num2) {
            return num1 + num2;
        } else {
            int subtracted = num1 - num2;
            return subtracted + sumOfPreviousN(subtracted, num2); 
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = 20;
        int num2 = 6;
        System.out.println(sumOfPreviousN(num1, num2));
    }
}

It feels like I need to use a 3rd variable that I'm missing, but there's definitely a way! I'm not sure how to, for this example, keep subtracting 6 while keeping track of both the values that are decreasing by 6 AND the values that are being added by the latter.

Please ask whoever gave you this assignment to clarify. What do they mean by sum of the first number? One value is not a sum. You would need to add it to something. But they then say minus multiples of the second argument. Huh? There are an infinite number of multiples of the second argument. The requirements are nonsense. And the examples don't help. There's no subtraction in the examples at all.

Is your program giving the expected output? Also when trying more examples? If  not, mention an example and mention the two arguments, expected result and observed result.

I understand the required result as (num1 - num2) + (num1 - 2 * num2). Is this correct?

@Anonymous no, it's num2 muliplied by each of its divisors. So if num2 = m*n then it's num2*m once and num2*n the second time.

What you are missing is the multiplier for the second number.

"feels like I need to use a 3rd variable that I'm missing" -- that is the value returned by the recursive method (the sum so far). Hint: what is expected from sumOfPreviousN(2, 6) ? (Check the base case)

by the way, your previous example was easier to understand: sumOfPreviousN(20,6) : (20-6) + (20-2*6) + (20-3*6) -- I assume no 4*6 since 20-4*6 < 0  || sumOfPreviousN(9,4) : (9-4) + (9-2*4)

My professor is known for being a bit tricky and it doesn't come super easily, unfortunately--sorry if I'm explaining poorly! This makes sense. I'm honestly not sure what my base case is even supposed to be--is it just n1 * n1 * n2?

the base case of a recursive algorithm is the trivial case (kind of the ending case) -- in posted code num1 <= num2

I think your base case was supposed to be num1 > num2. When num2 is greater or equal, return 0. Otherwise use your current recursion and something like,
public static int sumOfPreviousN(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 <= num2) {
        return 0;
    }
    int subtracted = num1 - num2;
    return subtracted + sumOfPreviousN(subtracted, num2);
}

Which I tested with your provided test cases,
System.out.println(sumOfPreviousN(9, 4) == 6);
System.out.println(sumOfPreviousN(20, 6) == 24);

And got
true
true

